# Python list in bytes format how to convert in regular list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have this kind of object:

```
lb = b'[5, "WEB9999", "Test 2", true]'
```

I try to convert it to a regular string for extract single values using:

```
ls = list(lb)
```

or

```
ls = list(str(lb))
```

but the results split every string in single chars

```
['b', "'", '[', '5', ',', ' ', '"', 'W', 'E', 'B', '9', '9', '9', '9', '"', ',', ' ', '"', 'T', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', '2', '"', ',', ' ', 't', 'r', 'u', 'e', ']', "'"]
```

How can I simply convert my bytes object in a python regular list for retrieving single value using `mylist[3]`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First convert the same to unicode by decoidng it to lb.decode('utf-8') then go for this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list

Answer (score 0):

Try lb.decode()

by default I think it takes utf-8

**EDIT**

-Whomever downvoted is probably doing it for fun
[Here's a test img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1QTO.png)

-This is not a duplicated question, especially not related to 'Parse Json in Python'